# OpenSLES: SL_RESULT_CONTENT_UNSUPPORTED

Tags: android, opensl

I see customer devices on Google Play store that have my app unable to realize the OpenSLES player object.

**static SLObjectItf playerObject;**

...

**result = (*playerObject)->Realize(playerObject, SL_BOOLEAN_FALSE);**

gives the error **SL_RESULT_CONTENT_UNSUPPORTED**.

```
    // Configure data format.
    static SLDataFormat_PCM pcm;
    memset( &pcm, 0, sizeof(pcm) );
    pcm.formatType = SL_DATAFORMAT_PCM;
    pcm.numChannels = 1;
    pcm.samplesPerSec = SL_SAMPLINGRATE_11_025;
    pcm.bitsPerSample = SL_PCMSAMPLEFORMAT_FIXED_16;
    pcm.containerSize = 16;
    pcm.channelMask = SL_SPEAKER_FRONT_CENTER;
    pcm.endianness = SL_BYTEORDER_LITTLEENDIAN;
    // Configure Audio Source.
    SLDataSource source;
    source.pFormat = &pcm;
    source.pLocator = &bufferQueue;

    // Create engine
    //LOGI("create audio engine");
    result = slCreateEngine
    (
        &engineObject,
        0, // numOptions
        NULL,
        0, // numInterfaces
        NULL,
        NULL
    );
    CHECK_SL( result, "slCreateEngine" );

    result = (*engineObject)->Realize(engineObject, SL_BOOLEAN_FALSE);
    CHECK_SL( result, "engineObject->Realize" );

    // get the engine interface, which is needed in order to create other objects
    result = (*engineObject)->GetInterface(engineObject, SL_IID_ENGINE, &engineEngine);
    CHECK_SL( result, "GetInterface ENGINE" );

    result = (*engineEngine)->CreateOutputMix( engineEngine,&outputMixObject, 0, NULL, NULL );
    CHECK_SL( result, "CreateOutputMix" );

    result = (*outputMixObject)->Realize(outputMixObject,SL_BOOLEAN_FALSE);
    CHECK_SL( result, "outputMixObject->Realize" );

    SLDataLocator_OutputMix loc_outmix = { SL_DATALOCATOR_OUTPUTMIX,outputMixObject };
    SLDataSink audioSnk = { &loc_outmix, NULL };

    // Create Audio player.
    const SLInterfaceID ids[2] = { SL_IID_ANDROIDSIMPLEBUFFERQUEUE, SL_IID_VOLUME };
    const SLboolean req[2] = { SL_BOOLEAN_TRUE, SL_BOOLEAN_FALSE };
    result = (*engineEngine)->CreateAudioPlayer(engineEngine, &playerObject, &source, &audioSnk, 2, ids, req);
    CHECK_SL( result, "CreateAudioPlayer" );

    // Realize Audio player.
    result = (*playerObject)->Realize(playerObject, SL_BOOLEAN_FALSE);
    CHECK_SL( result, "playerObject->Realize" );
```

I see this on devices like these:
Lenovo A1000, samsung/SM-T285, motorola/Moto G (4), ...

Is it complaining about the data format? It's not very exotic: PCM at 11025 Hz, 16 bit.

Comment: Did you ever figure this one out?

Comment: @MatthewStrom No, it was on customer devices, not my own.